# Removal of build info for what command

Tags: c++, gcc, solaris

```
bash-2.05$ what xxx
ndmpd:
     Product:      yyy
     Release:
     Build number: unknown user-2011-87
     Build date:   Mon Mar 28 20:51:25 2011
     Build arch.:  solaris
     Build info:   unknown host:/xx/yyy/zzz/vv/www,DBG=1,OPT=-O
```

when I run the `what` command on our executable (xxx). We don't want the following line to be printed.

```
Build info: unknown host:/export/home/murugs2/SI/dev,DBG=1,OPT=-O
```

I dunno how old programmers did this. I want to remove this. How to do it?
The src file(c++ code ) is compiled using gcc.

Comment: Does anyone know how to add the info like product name etc.. so it can be displayed by what commands?

Answer (score 2):

These strings correspond to SCCS version information patterns that are found in the target files.

You can strip off the unwanted one by patching you binaries but the simplest way would be to remove it from the source code. It will be easily locatable by looking for the "@(#)" token.

eg:

```
char sccsid[] = "@(#) Build info:   unknown host:/xx/yyy/zzz/vv/www,DBG=1,OPT=-O";
```

Answer (score 1):

This is usually stored in the ELF comments section, which can be viewed, deleted, added to, or replaced with the various options to the [`/usr/ccs/bin/mcs`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1461/mcs-1.html) command.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the compiled binary doesn't use it, there's no reason you can't edit the string away yourself (by changing all the characters to `-` or something). I don't know of a utility to do it, although `strip` *might* help you.

Comment: Patching will definitely work but "strip" won't help in that specific case as these strings are part of the executable data, not extra debugging or symbol information.